# EVAL/APPLY: too many arguments given to F

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

Hello why do i get `*** - EVAL/APPLY: too many arguments given to F` on function call with nested lists parameter. I cannot figure it out, since I passed a simple  nested list.

```
(defun f (L) 
    (cond 
        ((NULL l) nil)
        ((listp (car L)) 
            (append (F(car L))) (F(cdr L) (car (F (car L)))))
        (T (list(car L)))
    )
)

(setq A '((1) 2 3))
(f A)
```

Comment: can you please improve the formatting of your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This better formatting should make it easy to spot the error:

```
(defun f (l) 
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        ((listp (car l)) 
         (append (f (car l)))
         (f (cdr l)
            (car (f (car l)))))
        (t (list (car l)))))
```

If that does not help, use SBCL to compile the function. It will give you a very clear error message.

Comment: thanks... ` (f (cdr l)
            (car (f (car l))`